# add up even numbers in list using two nested for loops and the str() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.7

I am trying to get all of the even numbers from the list, using two nested loops and using str(). My code works, just not how I am intending it to and it is short of what I am looking for.

```
 def evnNmbr ():
     a = int(input("Enter 1st integer (lower) "))
     b = int(input("Enter 2nd integer (higher) "))
     evnCnt = 0
     for i in range (a, b):
         if i % 2 == 0:
             evnCnt += 1
             s = str(i)
             print("Even number count is , ", s, evnCnt)



 evnNmbr()
```

Ex

```
Enter 1st integer (lower) 0 
Enter 2nd integer (higher) 21 
Even number count is , 0 1 
Even number count is , 2 2 
Even number count is , 4 3 
Even number count is , 6 4 
Even number count is , 8 5 
Even number count is , 10 6 
Even number count is , 12 7 
Even number count is , 14 8 
Even number count is , 16 9 
Even number count is , 18 10 
Even number count is , 20 11
```

I would like to get the total number of even numbers between the range of numbers a and b. ie: `(2, 4, 6, 8 = 4 even numbers`

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output, and the output you have actually

Comment: Sorry, but what is your intended output?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified. "short of what I am looking for" is not a problem specification.  Your program hangs waiting for input -- don't make us design your testing; replace the `input` statements with test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to print the result `evn_cnt` once at the end

```
def evnNmbr():
    a = int(input("Enter 1st integer (lower) "))
    b = int(input("Enter 2nd integer (higher) "))
    evn_cnt = 0
    for i in range(a, b):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            evn_cnt += 1
    print("Even number count is", evn_cnt)
```

See

```
Enter 1st integer (lower) 10
Enter 2nd integer (higher) 88
Even number count is 39
```

Answer (score 0):

I added range of b + 1, because the range function excludes the last value, so if you put an even number at the end it wouldn't count. The only thing you have to modify really is to print separately the `evnCnt` variable, so it only shows the total value.

```
def evnNmbr ():
    a = int(input("Enter 1st integer (lower) "))
    b = int(input("Enter 2nd integer (higher) "))
    evnCnt = 0
    for i in range (a, (b + 1)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            evnCnt += 1
            # s = str(i)
            # print("Even number count is , ", s)
            # if you still want to visualize every number separately you can uncomment the lines
    print(f"Even number count is: {evnCnt}")


evnNmbr()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be your simplest solution

```
def find_evens(a,b):
    l = []
    for i in range(a,b):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l.append(i)

    answer = len(l)
    return answer

print(find_evens(1,21))
```